# Javascript executed even after SRI Integrity failure

Tags: javascript, security, subresource-integrity

I have a test page on local on 9180 port, which is loading JS from another port to simulate different domain.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/myscript.js" integrity="jRIKARJybgWRWqQslhFC5boBExY7MBLvUpMWYpuXuL1sDqCCp2Gd"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Testing SRI
</body>
```

**myscript.js**

```
alert('Hello');
```

On running this on browser, I see error on console, but alert is still fired

```
Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('jRIKARJybgWRWqQslhFC5boBExY7MBLvUpMWYpuXuL1sDqCCp2Gd'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
```

Am I missing something? Or its due to local that browser is allowing script to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since (as the error message says) the `integrity` attribute value itself is invalid, the browser isn't enforcing it.

Comment: Correct, it seems I made a mistake while adding that. Also it seems the resource needs to be CORS enabled to enforce integrity check.